# Is there a standard function that applies a list of predicates to a value until success?

Tags: hooks

I look for compacting expression like:

```
(let ( (val (complex-expr ...)) )
  (or (pred1 val) (pred2 val) ...(predN val)))
```

Instead I like something:

```
(apply-some (complex-expr ...) '(pred1 pred2 ... predN))
```

Comment: It is very similar to [`-some->`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#-some--x-optional-form-rest-more), except that you need to invert the predicates. But I don't know of any function that'd do it in standard library, so writing one yourself doesn't sound like a bad idea. Perhaps you could suggest this as a feature to Dash library maintainers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your request OK, this is exactly what `run-hook-with-args-until-success` does.  (There are also functions `run-hook-with-args-until-failure` and `run-hook-with-args`.)

```el
run-hook-with-args-until-success is a built-in function in `C source
code'.

(run-hook-with-args-until-success HOOK &rest ARGS)

Run HOOK with the specified arguments ARGS.
HOOK should be a symbol, a hook variable.  The value of HOOK
may be nil, a function, or a list of functions.  Call each
function in order with arguments ARGS, stopping at the first
one that returns non-nil, and return that value.  Otherwise (if
all functions return nil, or if there are no functions to call),
return nil.

Do not use ‘make-local-variable’ to make a hook variable buffer-local.
Instead, use ‘add-hook’ and specify t for the LOCAL argument.
```

See the Elisp manual, node [Running Hooks](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Running-Hooks.html).

Comment: Neat, I didn't know hooks may take arguments.

Comment: Thanks, as additinal goal for question I like to see function name, seems that there are no any standard in Lisp practice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32671159/ but Elisp have some, +1

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your "additional goal" comment. Could you elaborate? Or maybe pose a new question for it, if it is something different?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `cl-some` to apply a list of predicates to a value:

```el
(cl-some (lambda (p) (funcall p "some value"))
         '(vectorp listp stringp))
```

I suppose you could wrap this in a function. Although I don't love this name, say:

```el
(defun cl-emos (preds v)
  "Are any PREDS true for V.

This is the \"opposite\" of `cl-some', which sees if one pred is
true for any values."
  (cl-some (lambda (p) (funcall p v))
           preds))
```

Example uses:

```el
(cl-emos '(vectorp listp stringp)
         "string")
;; => t
(cl-emos '(vectorp listp stringp)
         42)
;; => nil
```

> Note: Whatever you name it, of course you shouldn't prefix it with `cl-`. I did that just to make the comparison clear with `cl-some`.

---

Compared to `cl-some`, I prefer the way that `ormap` works in Scheme and Racket: It returns the truthy value, not just `t` (even when the predicate only returns `t`).  To do that, here, just replace `(funcall p v)` with `(and (funcall p v) v)`:

```el
(defun cl-emos (preds v)
  "Are any PREDS true for V.

This is the \"opposite\" of `cl-some', which sees if one pred is
true for any values."
  (cl-some (lambda (p) (and (funcall p v) v)) ;; <======
           preds))

(cl-emos '(vectorp listp stringp)
         "string")
;; => "string"
(cl-emos '(vectorp listp stringp)
         42)
;; => nil
```

Of course now it's subtly different than using `cl-some` with the same predicate(s). But it lets you return the expensive expression's evaluated result and bind it, which seems closer to the spirit of you question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of an existing function to do this, but it's simple enough to write in plain Elisp.

```
(defun some-predicate (val predicates)
  (when predicates
    (or (funcall (car predicates) val)
        (some-predicate val (cdr predicates)))))
```

This returns `t` (the return value of the predicate that returns non-nil):

```
(some-predicate 1 '((lambda (val) (> val 2)) (lambda (val) (> val 0))))
```

This returns `nil`:

```
(some-predicate 1 '((lambda (val) (> val 2)) (lambda (val) (> val 1))))
```

Note that because it uses recursion, it could blow the stack if you have a long list of predicates.

Answer (score 0):

With help from https://stackoverflow.com/a/32690256/173149 there are another built-in into `cl-lib` alternatives which also available in CL:

```
;; analog for some.
(loop with value = (floor (* 10 (sin 9)))
      for pred in (list #'symbolp #'numberp)
      thereis (funcall pred value))

;; analog for every.
(loop with value = (floor (* 10 (sin 9)))
      for pred in (list #'numberp #'plusp #'evenp)
      always (funcall pred value))
```